# transfer android dev environment from one partition to another

Tags: android

I installed a fresh windows 7 to new partition into a new hard drive I:
My old partition is vista and has everything configured for android development.

I would like to ask for information on how to transfer my complete android dev to the new win7 without messing everything.

thank you to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For installation of Android you need 1.Android SDk 2. Eclipse and to run eclipse you required JDK.So If you have installed JDK then you can copy eclipse and Android-SDK in your I:.And copy your workspace to your I:. That's it.Otherwise first install JDK on your windows 7 and then follow rest of portion. :)

Comment: sweet. okie.so, install java runtime and copy paste everything else, and change path of SDK location..

Comment: @Ray Only the one important thing you have to do is you have locate the position of your Android-SDK when you start your eclipse first time. By using windows > Preferences > Android >(Your SDK Location).  :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste like how you normally do it.. In Eclipse re-set the values for paths pointing to android sdk to that of the new location.

Comment: where do i find these values?

Comment: Windows -> Preference -> Android, this will have a textbox SDK Location, enter the latest location of your android SDK here..

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the android-sdk directory to another partition.
But if you are using eclipse, you will need to re-configure sdk path in eclipse, which is at Window -> Preferences -> SDK Location

Also if you are using any other tools which need to know android location, you will need to re-configure its path.
For example, maven uses ANDROID_HOME environment variable.